# What is list of common integral that have no closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, big-list

What is list of common integral that have no closed form?

It's diffucult for me to google it for some reason.

Comment: What does "common" refer to...?

Comment: @Nameless I believe it means integrals used multiple times, and that are taught and/or learnt often.

Comment: Definite or indefinite integrals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals#Definite_integrals_lacking_closed-form_antiderivatives. This link tells you a list of integrals not expressible in a closed form expression.

Answer (score 1):

$ e^{x^{2}} $, for starters. Hope this helps! :)